# Left outer join is working with SQLite while is not with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, left-join

I have a table with products, orders, prices, date of sell. I need to create a table with the sells for a product in a single day. I used sqlite and this code worked just fine:

```
/* Groups order date <-> product */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableDate AS
SELECT DISTINCT A.orderDate, B.productName
FROM ordini AS A
CROSS JOIN ordini AS B;

/* Groups orders by product and date */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableOrders AS
SELECT COUNT(productQty) AS total, productName, SUM(totalAmount) AS amount, orderDate
FROM ordini WHERE (orderStatus >= 3)
GROUP BY orderDate, productName;

/* Selects the product sells data, grouped day by day */
SELECT orderDate, productName, COALESCE(total, 0) AS total, IFNULL(amount, 0) AS amount
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableOrders ON tableOrders.orderDate = tableDate.orderDate AND tableOrders.productName = tableDate.productName)
ORDER BY orderDate;
```

As I said, this code worked pretty fine with sqlite (with "TEMP VIEW" instead of "TEMPORARY TABLE"), but with mysql I get "*Every derived table must have its own alias*". So I have added an alias on the last select:

```
 /* Selects the data of sells, grouped by day */
SELECT orderDate, productName, COALESCE(total, 0) AS total, IFNULL(amount, 0) AS amount
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableOrders ON tableOrders.orderDate = tableDate.orderDate AND tableOrders.productName = tableDate.productName) AS MyAlias
ORDER BY orderDate;
```

and now I get "*Duplicate column name 'productName'*". Now I'm pretty sure I have tried almost every possible combination of table name and productName, but still can't get rid of that error.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableDate LEFT OUTER JOIN tableOrders 
ON tableOrders.orderDate = tableDate.orderDate 
AND tableOrders.productName = tableDate.productName
```

you select all the columns from both tables.
So in the result there are 2 columns named `productName` from the 2 tables (the same for the column `orderDate`) and this is not allowed.
In the select list specify only one of each column pair and any other column that you want and drop `*`:

```
SELECT d.productName, d.orderDate , ......  
FROM tableDate d LEFT OUTER JOIN tableOrders o 
ON o.orderDate = d.orderDate 
AND o.productName = d.productName
```

I used aliases for the table names to shorten the code.

Comment: You are definitely right, it works like a charm! Thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because the column `productName` exists in both `tableDate` and `tableOrders` in your sub-query, but the SQL Engine doesn't know which column to use because you're doing `SELECT *`, which pulls in all columns from both tables. The column names in a derived table need to be unique, so you're getting the error.

But you don't need the sub-select, or the `JOIN` at all. Your query could be simplified to:

```
SELECT 
     o.orderDate
    ,o.productName
    ,COALESCE(o.total, 0) AS total 
    ,COALESCE(o.amount, 0) AS amount 
FROM 
    tableOrders AS o
ORDER BY o.orderDate;
```

All of the fields you're selecting are from that table alone.